# ODI 12C. Compare two Numeric variables, get error

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I'm using Oracle Data Integrator 12C. When I trying to use Evaluate Variables to compare two Numeric type variables I get error:

ODI-1233: Error while evaluating variable the following expression: COM.val1 <= #COM.val2
Caused By: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN

TNX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The error is happend, when There is a blank space at the beginning of the phrase.
like this : COM.val1 <=[space was here]#COM.val2